# not able to push changes to a remote branch in github

Tags: git, github

I am a bit new in github and I am seeing something which never happened to me when using gerrit. I have a repo with three branches, let's call them ==> a,b,c. When I type

```
git branch -a
```

I can see:

```
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/a
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/b
  remotes/origin/c
```

Imagine I want to change something in b. I do the following:

```
 git checkout -b b_branch remotes/origin/b
```

Then I do the change. Add it and commit it. When I check the logs of git, I can see that there is one extra commit compared to the list of commits in the remore repo. Then, I do:

```
git push origin remotes/origin/b
```

However, nothing gets uploaded and I can see that it says:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

And if I do a simple push, it says: Everything up-to-date. However, the git log shows one extra commit.

Am I doing anything wrong? Why I can't commit my changes to the branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push the local `b_branch` to the remote `b` branch, write like this:

```
git push origin b_branch:b
```

When the name of the local branch is the same as the name of the remote branch, the syntax is simply:

```
git push origin branchname
```

When the names are different, you need to use the more verbose but explicit
syntax with `:` separating the local and remote branch names.

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thanks :)